# Adding text from Terminal in Ubuntu 20.04 to Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I just added a post to Stack asking for help and showed lines from my terminal to help clarify the question..

I tried placing it in the Blockquotes but that didnt look right so resorted to adding dashes at the beginning and end.

Please can you tell me what the correct method is for adding lines from my Terminal in future as Im sure I will be adding many more questions and would like to ensure they are in the correct format.

Many thanks!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Cool thankyou :)